# TFS lock options on checkout

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We want our team to start using the LockType: CheckIn (Allow other users to checkout but prevent them from checking in).
Once someone already has the file checked out, we want to switch to LockType: Unchanged for the subsequent users.

Currently we use CheckOut (Prevent other users from checking out and checking in).

On the checkout dialog , is there a way to make Checkin as the default instead of the "Unchanged - Keep any existing lock"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For you situation, if you want the check in be default, you can directly  [lock folders or files](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files). Follow below ways:

1. In **Source Control Explorer**, in a workspace, open the shortcut menu
   for the folder or file to which you want to apply a lock, and then
   choose Lock.(Right click it, select advance-lock)
2. In the **Lock** dialog box select the file or folder you want.
3. Choose either the **Check Out lock** or the **Check In lock** type, and then
   choose Lock.

Under Pending Changes, Source Control Explorer displays the status: lock. The next time pending changes are checked in, the lock will take affect.

**Note:** You can also lock folders and files from the command line. For more information, see [Lock Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/lock-command).

[image]